KVM/QEMU virtual machine problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 24
On Ubuntu 22 I created a Windows virtual machine on KVM/QEMU using the Virtual Machine Manager.
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24 I cannot run this machine any more. It says "shutoff" and when I try to run it (using the "play" button) I get the error message
Error starting domain:
unsupported configuration:
domain configuration does not support video model 'qxl'

When I open the VM I have the configuration items on the left (Overview, OS information, etc.) and there is an item "Video QXL" as well. On the right I can choose a value for the parameter "Model" with values "Bochs", "None", "QXL", "Ramfb", "VGA", and "Virtio".
Changing to another option and choosing "Apply" results in another error:
Error changing VM configuration:
unsupported configuration:
chardev 'spicevmc' not supported without spice graphics

In the "details" section below it says:
Error changing VM configuration: unsupported configuration: chardev 'spicevmc' not supported without spice graphics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addhardware.py", line 342, in change_config_helper
    define_func(devobj=devobj, do_hotplug=False, **define_args)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 923, in define_video
    self._process_device_define(editdev, xmlobj, do_hotplug)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 534, in _process_device_define
    self._redefine_xmlobj(xmlobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 391, in _redefine_xmlobj
    self._redefine_xml_internal(origxml, newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 374, in _redefine_xml_internal
    self._define(newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1137, in _define
    self.conn.define_domain(xml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 554, in define_domain
    return self._backend.defineXML(xml)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4543, in defineXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainDefineXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: chardev 'spicevmc' not supported without spice graphics

I had spice graphics installed in 22, does anyone know that the package name has changed? Is there a way to change the configuration so that I can run the existing VM?
(When I right-click on "Video QXL" item, I can choose to Add Hardware, but I cannot delete the "Video QXL" item itself -- that would have been the easiest I thought)
UPDATE
I followed @petercatania's advice and installed qemu-system-modules-spice, which added libspice-server1, but the error is still there.

QXL is what works for my Windows VMs created under 22.04 and running under 24.04.  I did add swtpm so I could install Windows 24h2, but 23h2 worked without that.

I set everything up according to someone's recipe, that also used QXL so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work now. I just copied from that recipe though, not based on knowledge about spice or QXL. The VM has a setting Channel (spice) in the left-hand menu, with just settings: Device type: spicevmc, Target type: virtio, Target name: com.redhat.spice.0. Could I maybe just remove that? I'm a bit reluctant to do so because in the Guest OS (Windows) I installed virtio packages for communicating with KVM (from virtio-win-0.1.215.iso).

I tested if building a new VM works OK and it does, with exactly the same spice/QXL options... Assuming some compatibbility issue between old VM and new KVM? Shame because going through all the windows updates is a right pain.

"sudo apt install qemu-system-modules-spice"
solved it for me after upgrading to to 24.04

Thanks! I followed your advice and installed qemu-system-modules-spice (APT added another package libspice-server1). Unfortunately the error persists.
